# Which is the order of the curve?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question about the order of a curve...

Which is the order of the curve $f(x, y)=1+2x-x^2$ at the point $(0,0)$?? Is it maybe $0$ because of the constant term ??

When we have for example $f(x,y)=2x^4+2y^2-3xy^2+x^2y^2$ the order is $2$, right??

How is it in this case when we have a constant term??

Comment: What definition of "degree of a curve" are you using?

Comment: That's a surface, not a curve. And what do you mean by degree?

Comment: The degree of a curve is not something that depends on a particular point -- it is a property of the entire curve as a single object. (Actually what you present as "curves" appear to be polynomials rather than curves, but the preceding sentence is equally true for "polynomial" instead of "curve").

Comment: @DanielHast $$f(x, y)=f_m(x-a, y-b)+ \dots +f_n(x-a, y-b), \text{ with }m \leq n$$ then the degree is $m$

Comment: And $2x^4+2y^2-3xy^2+x^2y^2$ has degree 4, not 2.

Comment: @MaryStar: What do $f_m$ and $f_n$ mean in your notation?

Comment: I meant "order" instead of "degree"

Comment: @DanielHast $f_i(x, y)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $i$

Comment: "Let $F$ be any curve, $P = (0, 0)$. Write $F = F_m +F_{m+1}+···+F_n$, where $F_i$
is a form in $k[X,Y ]$ of degree $i$, $Fm \neq 0$. We define $m$ to be the multiplicity of $F$ at $P = (0, 0)$, write $m = m_P (F)$. " Which is this $m$ in this case??

Answer (score 1):

I think you take the largest power and not the constant. The degree of the curve with x^4 would be 4th degree. even x^4 + b is a 4th degree.

Comment: I edited my post... I meant "order" instead of "degree"..

Comment: even though degree or order ! it has 4th degree and not 2

Comment: "Let $F$ be any curve, $P = (0, 0)$. Write $F = F_m +F_{m+1}+···+F_n$, where $F_i$
is a form in $k[X,Y ]$ of degree $i$, $Fm \neq 0$. We define $m$ to be the multiplicity of $F$ at $P = (0, 0)$, write $m = m_P (F)$. " Which is this $m$ in this case?

Comment: this is one  weird way to form a question. If I get this correctly they are aiming at superposition of functions, lets start of with an example define your curve as F(x,y) = x + y + 1. at P(0,0) you get F(0,0) = 1. lets say you can take F(x,y) = F1(x) + F2(y) + F3(x). making F1(x,y) = x, F2(x,y) = y and F3(x,y)= 1. so at P=(0,0) it would be 3. (I am guessing at this point because the question is super vague/ at this point this is what I understand of the question)